# exporting only filtered records in jquery-datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery-datatables in my application which displays more than 1000 records. I am using jquery table-tools extension to display buttons to save as `CVS` format. If a user enters a keyword in the global filter and hits `CSV`, I want to only export the filtered rows. How do I do I do it using Jquery-datatables? I tried the following code but was unsuccessful. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

```
var table=$('#dataTable-state').dataTable({
                        "jQueryUI": true,
                        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "aaData": $scope.data,
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "oSearch": {"bRegex":true, "bSmart": false},
                        "aoColumns": [
                            { "mData": "name" },
                            { "mData": "age" },
                            { "mData": "city" },
                            { "mData": "state" }
                        ]
                    });
                  var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table);

                $( tableTools.fnContainer() ).insertAfter('div#dataTable-state_wrapper');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the Table Tools options like the ones in here: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21730/exporting-only-filtered-data-using-tabletools-button-collections

Specifically the `"oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied'}` part of the code